# Too many commas

Tags: american-english, dates, parentheticals

Please join us Monday, August 1, 2016, for the 4th Annual Tee It Up for Down Syndrome Golf Tournament at Deer Run Golf Club in Victoria, Minnesota

Do I need a comma before and after the date?

Comment: This is exactly the problem with the American date format. Write it as "...join us on Monday 1 August 2016 for the 4th Annual..." and the problem disappears. **I'd** be happy to see your commas disappear as you suggest, but then I'm not American.

Answer (score 1):

Well the following would do too..

> Please join us, Monday August 1 2016, for the 4th Annual Tee It Up for
>   Down Syndrome Golf Tournament at Deer Run Golf Club in Victoria,
>   Minnesota

Comment: Why would you separate a restrictive element, the date, from what it modifies?

Comment: the date is adverbial, not restrictive

Comment: @deadrat You could argue that _Monday August 1 2016_ is a parenthesis; brackets or dashes would not be incorrect, so I suppose commas can't be either.

Comment: @AmI These are not mutually exclusive categories.  The date is not an aside, it's definitional .

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm guessing the second person pronoun is either indeterminate or projectional.  *I* would never argue that the date is a parenthesis.  Not with regard to the 4th Annual Tee It Up, anyway.

Comment: @deadrat I can only assume you're confusing 'parenthesis' with 'apposition'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yeah, I guess you can.

Comment: @deadrat I guess it would be less confusing if we removed the confusion, then.

Answer (score 0):

Like all punctuation issues, this is a matter of style, particularly for a venue as informal as the Deer Run Golf Club.  For what it's worth, the *Chicago Manual of Style* frowns on the day-date-year format, but if you insist, advises using commas to set off the date fore and aft, as you've done.